# Нужна помощь по api kodexplorer

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста каким образом из javascript закрыть собственное окно в  kodexplorer? Какую функцию top фрейма нужно вызвать и c какими параметрами? Или хотя бы подскажите, каким образом провести отладку, чтобы это выяснить, поскольку в js я не шибко силен.

Answer (score 0):

```
top.artDialog.get(window.name.replace("Open","")).close();
```